# Binding of two TextViews on vertical

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a `RelativeLayout` with a nested `LinearLayout` that contains two `TextViews` positioned horizontally relative to each other. This is `DiscountAmount` and `AmountWithDiscount`.

[image]

I need to keep the `DiscountAmount` and `AmountWithDiscount` always at the same level vertically, for this I put the android property in `LinearLayout`: `android:layout_below = "@ + id / textViewRowQuantity"`. But if the `Name` is too long and takes three lines, then it will go to `DiscountAmount`. If `Name` takes no more than 2 lines, then all is well.

Tell me, please, how can I solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSaleListRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIncQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:text="TextView" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDiscount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
  </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit" />
```

Add result:
[image]

**Implemented through ConstraintLayout. Thanks to all.**

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of lines in the `TextView` to 2 by adding this lines:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="2"
```

End ellipsize end means if the text is so long then it will be replaced with three dots ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSaleListRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30px"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIncQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
            android:text="text"
            android:minLines="2"/>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDiscount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowName"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show AmountWithDiscount is below to discount then change liner layout orientation like below .

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: At the relativeLayoutIncQuantity? Nothing changed

Comment: i am not understand your requirement. so pl provide image for how to display all textview.

Comment: I added a picture to my question, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSaleListRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIncQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rr_layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
        android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDiscount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rr_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make some change in liner layout..

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDiscount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TextViewsdfsdfdsgfd" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="textview" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```